# How to get key from multimap for value

Tags: java, dictionary, multimap

I am having Mutimap which contains following data.

```
Reports = {UserName1=[report1,report2,report3], UserName2=[report4,report5],UserName3=[report6,report7,report8],UserName4=[report9]}
```

I want to `getkey(report6)`for specific value from Multimap, output `UserName3`

Answer (score 0):

In **guava**, [filterValues](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#filterEntries%28com.google.common.collect.Multimap,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29) with your *predicate*, you can get the specified *entries*. Example:

```
    Multimaps.filterValues(testMultiMap, new Predicate<List<String>>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(List<String> strings) {
            return strings.contains("report6");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't preprocess the data, a `getkey()` query need to scan all values in all keys to get the position. If you have n querys and the map has m values totally, the algorithm complexity will be `O(n*m)`.

If you preprocess the data, map the value and the key in a new map, such as `newmap['report6'] = 'UserName3'` , the algorithm complexity will be `O(m+n)`.

So, when you have many queries, you should choose the second approach.